# What are adjectives for different levels of intoxication/drunkenness?

Tags: adjectives

I am trying to describe the increased drunkenness state of a character over a period of time, but the only two adjectives I know of are "tipsy" and "drunk". I would like the character to be shown going through more than just 2 such stages but I can't find adjectives that are specific enough. There are many synonyms for "drunk", many slang, but they pretty much mean the same thing. I am looking for more adjectives like "tipsy" which is very specific.

I could of course use something such as, fairly drunk, very drunk, extremely drunk etc, but I was wondering if there were any better options at all?

Comment: I wouldn't say *tipsy* is very specific at all. Any graduation (even the difference between fairly/very/extremely) is a matter of opinion. I suppose "completely comatose" is quite objective and specific, but up to that point, well...

Comment: There’s dozens, if not hundreds, of slang terms for being drunk. But I’m not sure any two people would agree on which order they apply.

Comment: There are probably more slang terms for *drunk* than for anything except masturbation. And I don't think there's a scale for either.

Comment: Do you want slang? If so, please tell us whether you want American English, British English, or some other form of English, the slang terms are different in different countries.

Comment: There's also _dead drunk_, which in theory means so drunk as to be comatose, but is sometimes used of people still able to walk about.

Comment: It may well be true that there is no complete consensus on which term for drunkenness corresponds to which degree of it (although there probably is consensus on, say, *wasted* representing a higher degree than *tipsy*). That, however, **is the answer** to the OP's question, rather than a reason for declaring it unanswerable.

Comment: Yes as mentioned and as jsw29 has alluded to, the purpose here is not to gather a full list of every possible synonym for drunkenness but to pick out the few that have the most consensus in how they are defined in terms of the level of drunkenness. I have attempted this in my answer below which uses synonyms that are most consistently defined across the major dicitonaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Dictionary.com I have managed to find the following (with the help of Thesaurus.com as well), which contains some slang but is fairly consistently defined across the major dictionaries at least:

- [Tipsy](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/tipsy?s=t): slightly intoxicated or drunk
- [Drunk](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/drunk?s=t): being in a temporary state in which one's physical and mental faculties are impaired by an excess of alcohol
- [Wasted](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/wasted?s=t): overcome by the influence of alcohol or drugs
- [Hammered](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/hammered?s=t): extremely intoxicated from alcoholic liquor or a drug

Answer (score 0):

There is the informal "**high**", which is free of the negative connotations of for instance, "drunk"; you can  use it then if you can make abstraction of those "dreaded and wise" connotations that the usual terms confer.

From [OALD, 14](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/high_1?q=high)

> [not before noun] high (on something) (informal) behaving in an excited way because of the effects of alcohol or drugs

There is also the formal term "**inebriated**" ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/inebriated?q=inebriated)), which does not confer any particular state of drunkenness and does not have as strong connotations as "drunk".

Comment: Related: [Can you get 'high' on alcohol or only 'drunk'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/387392/).